# Keep first element of array that is part of a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have this type of array

```
y 

array([299839, 667136, 665420, 665418, 665421, 667135, 299799, 665419, 667137, 299800])
```

as the result of a "top 10" `argpartition`:

```
y = np.argpartiton(-x, np.arange(10))[:10]
```

Now, I want to remove the elements that are sequential, only keeping the first (maximum) element in the series such that:

```
y_new
array([299839, 667136, 665420, 299799])
```

But while that seems like it should be simple I'm not seeing an efficient way to do it (or even a good way to start).  Assume the real-world application will do the top 1000 or so and need to do it many times.

Comment: it's unclear how does your condition *the elements that are sequential* relates to the 1st item `299839` in the result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Well there are islands of sequential numbers. That `299839` just happens to be only one in its island, so that's chosen. For other islands with more than one element the first occurrence is chosen.

Comment: @Divakar, is this island sequence `..., 667136, 5999900, 665420, 589111, 665421, ...` possible?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `[299839, 667136, 667135, 667137, 665420, 665418, 665421, 665419, 299799, 299800]`. In sorted order : `[299839, 667135, 667136, 667137, 665418, 665419, 665420, 665421, 299799, 299800]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach based on sorting -

```
# Get the sorted indices
sidx = y.argsort()

# Get sorted array
ys = y[sidx]

# Get indices at which islands of sequential numbers start/stop
cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([True], np.diff(ys)!=1 )))

# Finally get the minimum indices for each island and then index into
# input for the desired output
y_new = y[np.minimum.reduceat(sidx, cut_idx)]
```

If you would like to keep the order of elements in the output, sort the indices and then index at the last step -

```
y[np.sort(np.minimum.reduceat(sidx, cut_idx))]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [56]: y
Out[56]: 
array([299839, 667136, 665420, 665418, 665421, 667135, 299799, 665419,
       667137, 299800])

In [57]: y_new
Out[57]: array([299799, 299839, 665420, 667136])

In [58]: y[np.sort(np.minimum.reduceat(sidx, cut_idx))]
Out[58]: array([299839, 667136, 665420, 299799])
```

Comment: I figured there was a `reduceat` needed somewhere, I just wasn't seeing it.  Thanks Divakar.  The sorted version is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

heres my implementation for that problem

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


a = [299839, 667136, 665420, 665418, 665421, 667135, 299799, 665419, 
667137, 299800]
new = a[:]

# to keep the first number
b = a[0]
new.sort()
# to store diffrent arrays
saver = []
final_array = []

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(new), lambda (i, x): i - x):
    ac = map(itemgetter(1), g)
    saver.append(ac)

final_array.append(b)
for i in range(len(saver)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if a[j] in saver[i]:
            if b == a[j]:
                continue
            final_array.append(a[j])
            break


print final_array
```

output

```
[299839, 299799, 665420, 667136]
```

Comment: Problem is it doesn't give the expected output.  Neither the elements, nor the order.

Comment: corrected the output problem, and does the order matter